# ejabberdctl - how to remove user from room

Tags: ejabberd

I use [mod_rest](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib/tree/master/mod_rest) module for ejabberd. And i need to add and remove users from rooms from the command line.

Please, help me. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need `mod_rest` for that. Lastest ejabberd release support `mod_http_api` and can expose all ejabberd commands as API.

There is no command to kick a user from a MUC room. However, the command you should use is likely the one to change affiliation for the user.

If you set affiliation to `outcast`, the user will be kicked out of the room and prevented to join again.

For example, from command-line (ejabberdctl), it would be:

```
ejabberdctl set_room_affiliation room conference.localhost user123@localhost outcast
```

Similar command can be used from `mod_http_admin`.

Another option is also to use XMPP and let an admin account set the proper affiliation from a client or a bot.